# Is there a way to hide a specific Windows Update using C++ and WUA

Tags: c++, windows, windows-update, wuapi

Using the Windows Update Agent API, is there a way to hide updates? I have looked through the docs and I have not seen anything yet. Somebody has done it using VB but I need to use C++.

Edit: Here is a link to the VB script I found: https://serverfault.com/questions/145843/block-specific-windows-update-hotfix

Comment: Close voter: Read again. This is really about programming.

Comment: @m10950: How about showing that VB code?

Comment: @deviantfan Here: https://serverfault.com/questions/145843/block-specific-windows-update-hotfix

Comment: So what goes wrong when you use the solution shown in the answer you link to?

Comment: @HarryJohnston The code I linked to was in VB, I was wondering if there was a way to do this in C++

Comment: It's a COM interface, so it's language-independent.  (I know you can use COM from C++, though I'm not personally familiar with the techniques.  Looks like there's a fair number of existing questions on the subject.)